# Ember JS - Search over multiple models?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

As an example, if I had a person and address model and an address had many people and a person belonged to an address, how would I orchestrate a search to find every person where the address city field was 'Manchester'; for example.

After learning Ember over the past few weeks I can't wrack my brains to find out exactly how this would work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ember.RSVP.filter](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_filter) is very useful when filtering a list of records based in some asynchronous attributes, it wait until both the filtered array promise and callback promises are resolved and return another promise with the result:

```js
Ember.RSVP.filter(store.findAll('person', function (person) {
    return person.get('address').then(function (address) {
        return address.get('city') === 'Manchester';
    });
}).then(function (filteredPersons) {
    // filteredPersons are the persons who live on Manchester
});
```

If you already have the `person` array, you could pass it to `Ember.RSVP.filter` using [Ember.RSVP.resolve](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RSVP.html#method_resolve) so you don't have to make the backend call again:

```js
Ember.RSVP.filter(Ember.RSVP.resolve(persons), function (person) {
    ...
}).then(function (filteredPersons) {
});
```